# I can't export more than four artboards in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, artboard

I am trying to export artboards as PNGs from an AI file. I have a bunch of artboards created, but when I try to export the file and use the artboards, the export dialog only recognizes four artboards.

I've googled and searched all around and I can't seem to find any record of anyone else having this same problem.

See these examples: 
[image: a new file with 8 artboards]

However, when I try to export I get a dialog allowing me the option to only export 4:
[image]

If I try to change the range to something like "1-8", it still only saves artboards 1-4.

This same thing is happening when I try to save as a pdf, or any other thing in AI that uses the artboards. It only returns 4.

I've tried restarting AI, restarting my computer, but it still does the same thing.

I have Illustrator CS6, not the Creative Cloud, I have the single license, one time fee version.

Anyone ever run into this issue? It's driving me crazy.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried to save and restart and repeat the exporting? Try to locate which art boards are not exporting. Create new boards and copy your artwork to them. Never heard of this problem before.

Comment: I have tried that. I've tried several files with a bunch of artboards that I know was working a couple of weeks ago. It's always only 1-4. I can even rearrange the artboard order, but it still only exports 1-4.

Comment: File must be damaged. Or application prefs need dumped.. or application needs reinstalled. There's no limit to the number of artboards you can export other than the global 100 artboard limit in any AI file.

Comment: I agree with what the others have stated, but a Quick workaround for your situation would be to copy 5-8 into another doc and export the rest of your images.

Comment: What happens when you click "ALL" in that dialog box?

Comment: When I click "All" it still only exported the first four. I have fixed this by deleting the AI settings folder. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: @Scott, you are correct about the settings being corrupt. If you add an answer I'll mark it as correct so you can get some points. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the file must be damaged.
Or application prefs need dumped.. 
or application needs reinstalled.

There's no limit to the number of artboards you can *export* other than the global 100 artboard limit in any AI file.

Comment: It was indeed the preferences. In OSX, I dumped the preferences folder, restarted AI and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the preferences were corrupt and needed to be reset. I deleted the preferences folder, restarted, and sure enough I was able to export all artboards.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

See that i have marked in the attached picture change that to all which is right before i have marked, then try export , each and every Artboard will comes out,

Remember: check you clicked Use Artboards in dialog menu

Range is for if you need specific Artboard, you can mentioned which Artboard No. you need so that illustrator exports.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. See my original post. I tried doing that, but it still only exported the first four artboards. You can also see in my screenshot that "Use Artboards" is clicked. That's obviously not the problem that I'm having.

Answer (score -1):

Jeremy Check the box which is next to Use Artboards, U havent clicked All button in your screenshot, click and try it definitely it will work

Comment: Please read my original post In its entirity. I tried doing that, but it still only exported the first four artboards. Are you paying attention to the other comments and answers? I have already posted my own answer, and one of the commenters had the answer so I marked his as correct. This has been resolved. You don't have to keep answering.